# Center of gravity if $g$ varies for discrete particles (2D)

Tags: gravity, equilibrium

I understand that
$$x_{cog}=\frac{\sum{}^{}x_{i}m_{i}g_{i}}{\sum{}^{}m_{i}g_{i}}$$
but why does that holds for $y_{cog}$
$$y_{cog}=\frac{\sum{}^{}y_{i}m_{i}g_{i}}{\sum{}^{}m_{i}g_{i}}$$
if given $g$ on the negative direction of $y$ axis torque is the same for every point over the line of action of $F_{g}$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression for the $x$ co-ordinate of the COG is independent of the direction of the $x$ axis (the $x$ axis does not have to be perpendicular to the direction of gravity), so the same expression can be used for the $y$ co-ordinate of the COG as long as we replace $x_i$ by $y_i$. We can see this as follows.

If we have a *parallel* gravitational field, where the magnitude of $\vec g$ varies with position but its direction is constant, then

$\vec g(\vec r) = g(\vec r) \hat g$

where $\hat g$ is a unit vector in the (constant) direction of $\vec g$. If the position of the $i$th particle is $\vec r_i$ then the torque exerted by the weight of the $i$th particle about a given point $P$ at position $R_P$ is

$(\vec r_i - \vec R_P)\times m_i \vec g(\vec r_i) = m_i g(\vec r_i) (\vec r_i -\vec R_P)\times \hat g$

where $m_i$ is the mass of the $i$th particle. If we can find a point $P$ such that

$\displaystyle \sum_i m_ig(\vec r_i)( \vec r_i -\vec R_P)= 0$

then the net torque about $P$ will be zero and $P$ is, the definition, the COG of the set of particles. Replacing $g(\vec r_i)$ by $g_i$, we have

$\displaystyle \sum_i m_ig_i\vec r_i = \vec R_{cog} \sum_i m_ig_i
\\ \displaystyle \Rightarrow \vec R_{cog} = \frac {\sum_i m_ig_i \vec r_i}{\sum_i m_ig_i}$

Replacing $R_{cog}$ by its co-ordinates $(x_{cog}, y_{cog})$ (using any axes we like) and $r_i$ by its co-ordinates $(x_i, y_i)$ and you get the two separate but symmetric expressions for $x_{cog}$ and $y_{cog}$.